# Reading in netCDF data from THREDDS fails

Tags: python, python-xarray, thredds

I am trying to load in netcdf from a THREDDS server but experience an unrecognizable error after a certain timestep.

```
def list_dates(start, end):
    num_days = (end - start).days
    return [start + dt.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(num_days)]

start_date = dt.date(2017, 3, 1)
end_date = dt.date(2017, 3, 31)
date_list = list_dates(start_date, end_date)
window = dt.timedelta(days=5)

url = 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/OisstBase/NetCDF/V2.0/AVHRR/{0:%Y%m}/avhrr-only-v2.{0:%Y%m%d}.nc'
#url2=  'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/Datasets/noaa.oisst.v2.highres/icec.day.mean.{0:%Y}.v2.nc'
data = []
cur_date = start_date
for cur_date in date_list:
    print(cur_date)
    date_window = list_dates(cur_date - window, cur_date + window)
    url_list = [url.format(x) for x in date_window]
    window_data=xr.open_mfdataset(url_list).sst
    data.append(window_data.mean('time'))
    print(data[-1])

dataf=xr.concat(data, dim=pd.DatetimeIndex(date_list, name='time'))
print (dataf)
```

Loading in of this data goes smoothly until March 22 which is the fail date. I have tried changing months and years, and every time the script fails at the 22nd timestep. There happen to be two error codes which I will provide below. Any info on what is going on here would be greatly appreciated. For reference, I am running the latest versions of python and netCDF4, as well as xarray.

Errors:

Error 1: `KeyError: [<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset'>, ('https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/OisstBase/NetCDF/V2.0/AVHRR/201703/avhrr-only-v2.20170322.nc',), 'r', (('clobber', True), ('diskless', False), ('format', 'NETCDF4'), ('persist', False))]`

Error 2: `OSError: [Errno -37] NetCDF: Write to read only: b'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/OisstBase/NetCDF/V2.0/AVHRR/201703/avhrr-only-v2.20170322.nc'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the underlying issue is, but there seems to be something going sideways between the xarray netcdf4 cache and the netCDF-C library. If you add the following somewhere before your `for` loop:

```
xr.set_options(file_cache_maxsize=10)
```

that will help make sure any files (or `netCDF4.Dataset` objects, in this case) in the cache get cleaned up when you are done with them, and the underlying issue is avoided (not sure for how long, but I ran the code from `2017-03-01` to `2017-05-31` without an error).

Again, not sure exactly what is happening, but probably worth a opening a [github issue with xarray](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md&title=). It might not be an issue at the `xarray` level, but it will get to the right place from there.